# isEmpty() not working in Protractor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

As we all know, we have something like this in Java for selenium.

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("xxx").isEmpty()
```

Is there anything like this in JavaScript for automation testing using Protractor??

*Points to note: The application I use is NOT an angular app.*

My code block goes by:

```
if(browser.driver.findElementsByXPath("xxx").isEmpty()){
console.log();
}
```

The function that I tried with is:  `isDisplayed().toBeTruthy();`

The error i get is: findElement(...).isDisplayed(...).toBeTruthy is not a function

Answer (score 1):

There is **no method as isEmpty() in protractor** at least not available on protractor official api [docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api). But yes isEmpty() is a java method to verify if a string is empty or not

Usage of **isDisplayed** method in protractor

```
var foo = element(by.id('foo')); // equivalent of driver.findElement(By.id("foo"))

expect(foo.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); // equivalent of assert in java/testng
```

Comment: Note that empty tags will return false for `isDisplayed()`, even if the element itself is not hidden.You could also use `foo.idDisplayed().toEqual("");`

Comment: I am getting the error isDisplayed() is not a function

Answer (score 0):

*isEmpty() can retrieve True or False value based on String length,*

**- It returns true if String has 0 length,**

**- It returns false if String has >0 length,**

In Selenium Java also, It can not directly handle by findElement() method, It need to first retrieve text value from the element by getText() method and then it can check for value.

You can refer below Example for Java,

```
String getdata = driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).getText();
System.out.println(getData.isEmpty()); //It prints value true or false
```

**isEmpty() function only applicable for String variable.**

Like wise you can implement same for protactor.

Comment: In protractor `element(by.xpath("...")).getText()` returns a promise. In order to print the actual text you have to implement a callback like this: `element(by.xpath("...")).getText().then( function(result) { console.log(result); }); `. For `expect` this is not required, because it knows how to handle promises.

Answer (score 0):

All protractor and selenium-webdriver for Javascript API are async and return promise. More detail can be found from below API doc and source code.

[findElements API doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html)

[findElements source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L949)

```
var size = browser.driver.findElements(by.xpath("...")).then(function(eles){
  // eles is a javascript array
  return eles.length;
});

expect(size).toEqual(2) // use jasmine assertion api

expect(size).to.eventually.be(2) // use chai and chai-as-promised assertion api
```